# Predeterminar valores en un vector en Java

Tags: java, array

Hola amigos quiero que en un vector utilizando `System.out.print` Pueda predeterminar valores en el vector, ejemplo:

`Alumnos[]` -  Quiero predeterminar valores.. como nombres en el caso de ese vector, en JAVA, me ayudan por favor?.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, por lo que tengo entendido sería 
Alumnos[nombre1,nombre2,nombre3] esto lo haces donde declares el vector.

Comment: Y para una asignacion directa... es decir.. quiero que el alumno carlos tenga como calificacion predeterminada 4.0 , en ese caso como seria?

Comment: Para poder tener calificaciones para un alumno lo mejor es que crees una clase alumno con un dato miembro *calificación*. El array será de objetos alumno, accediendo a cualquier elemento del array podrás asignar una calificación por ejemplo con un método *alumno.ponerCalificación(4)*. Vendría muy bien que explicases algo más para poderte ayudar mejor.